# is it possible to read and listening log file change in rust

Tags: rust

I have a log file `/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/rust-learn/app.log`, this log file already contains some content and append new log by another process. Is it possible to read the log and watch the log change using rust? when other process append content into log file, read the new log content async, I have tried this code:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufReader, Seek, SeekFrom, BufRead},
};

fn main() {
    let file_path = format!(
        "{}",
        "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/rust-learn/app.log"
    );
    let file = File::open(file_path);
    if let Err(err) = file.as_ref() {
        println!("Error opening file: {:?}", err);
    }
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file.unwrap());
    let pos_result = reader.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0));
    if let Err(err) = pos_result.as_ref() {
        println!("Error seeking file: {:?}", err);
    }
    let mut pos = pos_result.unwrap();
    loop {
        let mut line = String::new();
        if reader.read_line(&mut line).unwrap() > 0 {
            println!("{}", line);
        }
        let len = reader.seek(SeekFrom::End(0)).unwrap();
        if len > pos {
            pos = len;
            reader.seek(SeekFrom::Start(pos)).unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

seems did not work. there is no other dependencies. I also tried the tail like this:

```
use std::{
    io::{BufReader, BufRead},
    process::{Command, Stdio},
};
use tokio::task;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut cmd = Command::new("tail")
        .arg("-f")
        .arg("/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/rust-learn/app.log")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    let stdout = cmd.stdout.take().unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(stdout);
    task::spawn_blocking({
        move || {
            for line in reader.lines() {
                if let Ok(line) = line {
                    let msg_content = format!("{}\n", line.to_owned());
                    print!("{}", msg_content);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

when I file changed, the stdout will output the full new file. Is it possible to diff output?

Comment: You can look at [notify](https://crates.io/crates/notify) crate which allows you to receive notifications about changes in the filesystem. So you could advance file cursor when you receive notification that something was appended to a file.

Comment: However maybe you should do a different architecture. Maybe you could read those logs from stdin and use `tee` to save them to your log file and pipe copy to your program. Then reading new logs would be as simple as reading from stdin.

Comment: the log was genreate by other process.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was thinking about something like this (in shell): `logging_process | tee process.logs | reading_process`. If this is possible in your use case, then it could greatly simplify your problem.

Comment: or if the logging process writes to the file directly, you can do `tail -f process.logs | reading_process` and read from `stdin`